# Table partitioning with sequence field in postgresql12

Tags: postgresql

Is there any problem when creating partitions of a table which has got seqence (nextval) as one of its field in postgresql 12?

Regards,
Seenu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a `bigserial` or identity column in a partitioned table, all partitions you create will share the same sequence. Consequently, auto-generated values will be unique across the whole partitioned table.